# java zip folder then delete original folder

Tags: java, zip, delete-file

I have a class that compresses the folder "UNO", which contains three ".txt" files, into a zip file called "UNO.zip", and I have another class that recursively deletes the original folder "UNO" and all its contents. When I execute them separately, they work like a charm. But when I try to execute them in the same thread the compression goes fine but the deleting part just deletes the last ".txt" file inside the folder... and I have to run the class two more times so that it will delete the ".txt" files and finally the original folder.

Can anyone tell me why this happens? 
Thanks.

This is the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Z3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        String ruta = "C:\\DESCARGAS\\";
        String nombreDeLaCarpeta = "UNO";
        List<String> nombresDeLosArchivos = new ArrayList<String>();

          File carpeta = new File( ruta + nombreDeLaCarpeta );
          File[] listadoEnCarpeta = carpeta.listFiles();
                if ( listadoEnCarpeta != null ) {
                    for ( int i = 0; i < listadoEnCarpeta.length; i ++ ) {

                        nombresDeLosArchivos.add( listadoEnCarpeta[i].getPath().substring( ruta.length() + nombreDeLaCarpeta.length() + 1, 
                                listadoEnCarpeta[i].getPath().length() ) );

                    }
               }

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        FileInputStream in = null;
        ZipOutputStream zos = null;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream( "C:\\DESCARGAS\\UNO.zip" );
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        zos = new ZipOutputStream( fos );

        for ( int i = 0; i < nombresDeLosArchivos.size(); i ++ ) {
            ze = new ZipEntry( nombresDeLosArchivos.get(i) );
            try {
                zos.putNextEntry( ze );
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                in = new FileInputStream( ruta + nombreDeLaCarpeta + "\\" + nombresDeLosArchivos.get(i) );
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            int len;
            try {
                while ( ( len = in.read( buffer ) ) > 0 ) {
                    zos.write( buffer, 0, len );
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }

            try {
                in.close();
                zos.closeEntry();
                zos.flush();
                zos.close();
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // ------------------------------------------------------------

            File directory = new File( ruta + nombreDeLaCarpeta );
            if ( directory.exists() ) {
                    try {
                        eliminarSubcarpetas( directory );
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }


    }

    public static void eliminarSubcarpetas( File file ) throws IOException {

        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if ( files != null ) {
            for ( File f: files ) {
                if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                    eliminarSubcarpetas( f );
                } else {
                    f.delete();
                    System.out.println( f.getAbsolutePath() );
                }
            }
        }


      file.delete();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple matter of output streams not being closed properly. I just had to put the compressing block in a different method and that did the trick.

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Z2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  {

        List<String> nombresDeLosArchivos = new ArrayList<String>();

        File carpeta = new File( "C:\\DESCARGAS\\UNO" );
        File[] listadoEnCarpeta = carpeta.listFiles();

                if ( listadoEnCarpeta != null ) {
                    for ( int i = 0; i < listadoEnCarpeta.length; i ++ ) {

                        nombresDeLosArchivos.add( listadoEnCarpeta[i].getPath() );

                    }
               }

            zipArchivo( "C:\\DESCARGAS\\UNO.zip", nombresDeLosArchivos);

            File directory = new File( "C:\\DESCARGAS\\UNO" );
            if ( directory.exists() ) {

                    try {
                        eliminarSubcarpetas( directory );
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }   
            }


    }

    public static void zipArchivo( String zipFile, List<String> listaDeStrings ) throws IOException {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( zipFile );
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream( fos );

        for ( int i = 0; i < listaDeStrings.size(); i ++ ) {

            File scrFile = new File( listaDeStrings.get(i) ); 
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ( scrFile );
            zos.putNextEntry( new ZipEntry ( scrFile.getName() ) );

            int length;

            while ( ( length = fis.read( buffer) ) > 0 ) {
                zos.write( buffer, 0, length );
            }

            zos.closeEntry();

            fis.close();

        }

        zos.close();


    }

    public static void eliminarSubcarpetas( File file ) throws IOException {

        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        if ( files != null ) {

            for ( File f: files ) {
                  if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                    eliminarSubcarpetas( f );
                } else {
                    f.delete();
                }
            }
        }

        file.delete();

    }

}
```